# Dell XPS 15 Keyboard typing double characters in Gnome Software Center

Tags: server, gnome, keyboard, xps

This is very weird. I had just installed Ubuntu server and Gnome. Typing in the search bar of the Gnome Software center results in double characters.

I haven't faced this anywhere else yet.

Also I cannot access the software sources where I can install hardware drivers and such.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this bug, but I was able to solve the problem by installing `ubuntu-software` instead of `gnome-software`.

Comment: This seems to have been solved. I updated my system yesterday and the problem seems to no longer exist. Try updating your system